# How to wait a certain amount of time before executing another line of code in a batch file

Tags: time, batch-file, wait, execute

Here's the thing, basically I need like a minute to pass after LineOfCode1 has executed before LineOfCode2 executes. Any ideas? Any help is highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

from the prompt, try

```
timeout /?
```

Comment: I have this code

@echo off

start OUTLOOK.EXE

start "" "C:\Documents and Settings\gmoran\My Documents\Downloads\USAP Phone Client.application"

start "" "C:\Documents and Settings\gmoran\Desktop\Desktop\npp.6.3.3.bin\notepad++.exe"

But due to the fact that notepad is a lighter program than outlook, it opens up faster. I need a little bit of time before it does that so that oulook will completely load up before notepad opens up.

Comment: So execute `timeout /?` from the prompt and follow the instructions. Insert the timeout command before the `start...notepad...` That would actually be quicker than posting, deleting, re-posting and waiting for a reply. It's a simple command.

Comment: @foxidrive Ah - XP - the W98 of the 21st century...Certainly. OP could have spent 10 seconds finding out whether my suggestion suited, but sadly appears to adhere to the ask-advice-then-argue school and spent far longer pursuing that philosophy. Now another choice would be `choice` but it too is not in XP, unless you have the resource kit (from memory.) And then there's `soon` from the resource kit. Or there's the `ping` option as you suggest. Of these, `timeout` is the simplest. Beats me why people insist on making things complicated - it really does.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use PING to delay if your OS doesn't have timeout.exe

```
@echo off
start OUTLOOK.EXE 
ping -n 60 localhost >nul
start "" "C:\Documents and Settings\gmoran\My Documents\Downloads\USAP Phone Client.application" 
start "" "C:\Documents and Settings\gmoran\Desktop\Desktop\npp.6.3.3.bin\notepad++.exe"
```